# Statistics on [FID] from table window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics

Try to do this

[image]

and you'll get an error message. However you can easily get statistics on [FID] using Summary Statistics tool. Somebody has a good explanation of this? Also note that from within the table [FID] is treated like non-numeric 'field'.

Extended question:

Statistics on [FID] can be very quick way to complete many tasks. For example find duplicates stored in other field. In example below field [COORD] stores string equivalent of point coordinates:
[image]

If I apply Summary Statistics tool, case field [COORD], statistics field [FID] and join resulting table back to original points table using [COORD]. I can find duplicate points using query

```
"pnts.FID" <> "st.FIRST_FID"
```

[image]

There are very many other tasks that can be accomplished using sequential record number.

My question is WHY one cannot perform statistics from TABLE VIEW(window), which is very fast way to perform statistics on the field, and at the same time this can be done using Summary Statistics tool. That is not so quick, because it is a long way down the tree System Toolboxes-Analysis Tools-Statistics.

Comment: The FID in a shapefile is not static, it changes all the time. When a shapefile is edited the FIDs are renumbered every time you save... why do you need a statistic on FID? Also, the FID is not *actually* in the table! Open a .dbf from a shapefile in Microsoft Excel (or equivalent) and you will see the field doesn't actually exist.

Comment: One of the things is finding duplicates in the table. Also can be very helpful with naming, e.g. multiple streams discharging to the same node. Yes I know that it is not in the table, this is why 'field' in my original Q

Comment: There shouldn't ever be a duplicate FID, they are managed by (in this case) Esri drivers. To use the FID for something meaningful create a field (I call mine bOID for beginning OID) and calc the field with your FID - now it's static. Refresh with a new copy whenever it's convenient or the values become too stale to trust.

Comment: It's treated like a non-numeric field because it's a special data type of 'Object ID' - it *isn't* a numeric. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000z000000 And in theory you can't have a duplicate FID, because the whole point is that FID/OIDs must be unique. If you do have duplicates, you've got an error.

Comment: I am finding duplicates not in [FID] guys. In the example shown I can use it to find duplicates in [PAR_ID]. I just join statistics table back to original and query ones where [FID]<>....[FIRST_FID]

Comment: Due to the transient nature of FID values it's dangerous to join to them. If you want to join to the objectid make it a file/personal geodatabase feature class - OBJECTIDs are unique, ascending and static for the life of the feature...

Comment: I am joining by [PAR_ID]

Comment: I feel that I have to extend my question

Comment: It may be better to ask a new question rather than extending this one, because to do so may invalidate the answer that @ChrisW has already expended effort into answering.

Comment: I don't follow your duplicate detection comment. If you get the first FID as a statistic, that just means the first FID it hits when it records a unique value for a particular field you're summarizing is what gets recorded. If FID=FIRST_FID, that's the first record it counted when summarizing PAR_ID. If FID<>FIRST_FID, those are all the other features that have the same PAR_ID. I suppose that does make them duplicates, but determining an original vs a duplicate is then based solely on the order in which either they were drawn or that summarize read the table.

Comment: Very much correct. I treat first one as original, the rest down the table are duplicates. It is oK in many cases. Suumarise always reads from [FID]=0 down, unless there is a selection

Comment: For your purposes obviously that works. I suppose if anything with the same PAR_ID is in the same geographic location, it works. If whatever attribute you're doing that with has different locations though, you're picking a random feature/record to represent all those that share the same value.

Comment: I finally understood the actual question. :) Last revision to add the bold reason.

Comment: I am truly sorry guys about my way of putting English words together:) The behaviour of summarise from TABLE VIEW is just one of those annoying little things that makes a work of consultant a wee bit hard

Comment: I think your English is fine and not an issue. It was more it's a very subtle question and a non-standard, if innovative, use of the tool(s). And, for me at least, reading through the question/issue too fast and focusing on tangent details. The only thing that might have made it more obvious would be inclusion of the error box in the first image as well as the dialog (big red Xs tend to draw attention). As a UI tip, I rarely drill through the toolbox tree to find things - I just type the name into the search box and run it from there.

Comment: Thanks. Frankly I use search as well, but when tree is extended, e.g. few workspaces open, the tool could be very well at the bottom. The story with table view came from ArcView 3 (I still have it and love it): Table-Field-Summarise. By habit I do it with ArcGIS, causes a bit of frustration every time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *actual* FID or OID field is not a numeric field. It is a special data type known as Object ID. See the help files

- http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006z00000009000000
- http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000z000000

If you run some tool that outputs a table with an attribute field based on the FID, for instance Near, that field is of data type LONG.

If you perform a Summary Statistics on the *actual* FID field, the data is treated as a numeric type by the tool. If you attempt the same from the attribute table, it's treated as a string (hence the First and Last options, but none of the numeric). Actually, that's a somewhat faulty statement - it's more *like* a string. Since the FID is unique, you can get either the first or last value associated with each value in the field you're summarizing on. But *math* operations on such unique id values are meaningless, just like they would be for any text string values. So even though you can *do* it in Summary Statistics, the result doesn't mean anything. In much the same way Zip Codes aren't numbers, neither are FIDs even if they're represented by numeric characters.

I don't know for sure how it treats it with a join operation, but I believe it must be numeric based on the joins that are successful (doubt you can join based on the FID field to a string field even if the strings are matching numbers).

Depending on where you look at it, the OID can be converted to different data types (see last link) but within ArcGIS it is its own animal.

More info (including differences between OID and FID, including renumbering):
http://support.esri.com/de/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37480
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v00000002000000

---

So to summarize that big paragraph up there and answer why you can't run statistics on the FID field itself from the table is because those statistics are meaningless:

- Count = number of records or that -1
- Min = 0 or 1
- Max = number of records or that -1
- Sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6... + number of records or that -1

and so forth. Null might be useful, except in order to be an FID/OID the value cannot be Null, so that statistic would always be 0. Only your First/Last statistic, which can be accessed from either place, serves any purpose as you demonstrate in your example. But (and here I had an ah_HA! moment) you're right, that causes an error. **The only explanation I can offer is that the attribute table Summarize and Summary Statistics are two different tools (hence you can use CASE with one but not the other) and must handle the Object ID data type in different ways.** Technically, it shouldn't work in Summary Statistics (and even throws an error warning when you first set it, but does it anyway).

Similarly you cannot Summarize on the FID field because every value in FID is unique - hence the summary table will look exactly the same as the attribute table.

Comment: +1 from me simply because my question was not so clear, so you don't waste your efforts. I just think that ESRI should fix it and/or remove [FID] from the list. I mean TABLE VIEW