# Joining shapefiles based on FID in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, qgis-2.8

I want to join shapefiles (or a shapefile and a data file) based on their mutual FIDs and can't see the FID in the "Target Field" dropdown on the join form.
I believe this is a basic need to have joins based on FIDs, so either I am doing it the wrong way or maybe something is missing here. {QGIS 2.8.1 on Linux}

Comment: Just to confirm, both your files are loaded into QGIS and both have an _FID_ attribute field?

Comment: You should never join layers on FID, since they are an auto field, and are not guaranteed to be preserved across operations such as Export, append etc.

Comment: @Joseph not an explicit one, but on the attribute table my far-left is my FID.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Well I am not changing the features' geometries, just am playing with the attributes, do you think that would also lead to false/misleading results?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133161/ It's from an ArcGIS perspective - I don't know how QGIS or the tools within handle FID fields - but the general issues/causes are outlined there. I will disagree with @DevdattaTengshe that you should *never* join based on FID (after all, what use would the Near or Generate Near Table tools, or anything else that produces results with FID identifier attributes be?), however it is a good point and important to understand the implications, how they work, and that they aren't necessarily preserved over time.

Comment: One thing that does come to mind and is likely the same between QGIS and Arc is that join fields must share the same data-type. In your table/datafile, is the FID field a numeric? This is somewhat discussed at the question I linked to (how the FID field, which is technically its own special datatype, is interpreted by different tools/software).