# Max value from two columns in ArcGIS table query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, definition-query

I'm looking for a tool that will select just these certain features (mark them in a new column or just delete all other features). It´s the highest number of "OBJECTID" for every number of "arcid".

[image]

Comment: I'd copy it to shape file, sort descending by object I'd and delete identical arcid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd warn you against using the `OBJECTID` field for anything, the values in it can change when the layer is edited. I'm guessing what you're trying to do here is find the most recent version of each feature. Using `OBJECTID` for that will *probably* work, as long as the layer hasn't had features deleted from it.

You can use the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) tool to find the maximum value in a field based on values in another field. In this case you would run the tool using `arcid` as the CASE field and `OBJECTID` as the Statistics field with MAX as the Statistics Type. I'm not sure that you can actually use the `OBJECTID` field in geoprocessing like this, you may have to create a new field and copy the values in `OBJECTID` to it, then use that new field as your Statistics field.

Comment: No need in additional field https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133161/statistics-on-fid-from-table-window